# How to setup a PHP API to work over HTTPS?

Tags: mysql, php, ssl, https, mariadb

I use a simple API with PHP to get some values in JSON format, it is working fine in web browser over HTTP.
I enabled SSL in mariadb with the certificates, but when I try my API using HTTPS, it says connection failed, instantly.

Do I need to enable something in my API ?

Comment: Do you have logs that have more detailed information?

Comment: No I don't have logs, but it should work like that ? There is no code to write in the API to handle HTTPS ?

Comment: HTTPS is a protocol for web connections. It has nothing to do with your app's connections to MariaDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser talks to a web server, which talks to PHP, which talks to MariaDB. If you enable SSL between PHP and MariaDB, that will not enable HTTPS between your browser and the web server. You need to configure HTTPS on the web server.

Comment: Thanks I'm figuring this out, trying to enable ssl in apache

Comment: I set up ssl.conf in httpd folder and it's working, thanks again !